# What's the in-universe reason for a lack of monsters in Thief 4?

Tags: thief-series

The [Thief series of games](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thief_(series)) is somewhat famous for its [fantasy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fantasy)/[steampunk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steampunk) atmosphere, often including fantastical creatures like zombies, monsters, ghosts, etc. as opponents. However, in the most recent (fourth) [entry of the series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thief_(video_game)), there is a noticeable lack of any non-human enemies. The closest thing we get to a non-human enemy is the

> Primal Humans, which are people warped into a [Gollum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gollum)-like form by the Primal Stone.

In the prior games, areas of The City were rife with giant spiders, rat-creatures, zombies, spirits, etc. **Is there an explanation in-universe for the sudden disappearance of these creatures?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer, it's an [entirely different continuity](http://thief.wikia.com/wiki/Thief_%28reboot%29).

> Thief (originally labeled THI4F) is a reboot of Eidos' award winning Thief series .... Thief is not a prequel or sequel to the original games, it is a reboot of the franchise with only a few elements of the original...

So there are no monsters in this game because the world doesn't have those monsters.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W2P1DjM8TCA